# Excel Macro to copy from sequential rows to constant location, then from constant location back to matching row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making my first macro in order to save having to perform 2500 copy-pastes. I have a long and complicated `worksheet` that takes two variables as inputs and returns a single value, and another `sheet` with 2500 pairs of these variables.

To keep things in the same sheet, I've linked the formula sheet inputs to `J2` and `K2` on my variable `sheet`, and the output to `L2`. My goal is to populate a third column next to the first two with the results for that row, by copying the two values to `J2` & `K2`, then copying from `L2` to the appropriate cell in the third column. As my macro is currently, it returns to the same cell in the third column every time, based on an offset from `L2` as the last active cell.

I've tried searching for help on how to either increment the last paste operation, or to keep the active cell referencing the start point of the macro in order to keep things in the same row, but was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ActiveCell.Range("A1:B1").Select
Selection.copy
Range("J2:K2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("L2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.copy
ActiveCell.Offset(43, -5).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TT()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, c As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    For Each c In sht.Range("A1:A2500").Cells
        sht.Range("J2").Value = c.Value
        sht.Range("K2").Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
        sht.Calculate
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = sht.Range("L2").Value
    Next c
End Sub
```